# Achemso package doesnt display all fields form the reference

Tags: achemso

This is in my tex file:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myreferences}
```

And this in my bib file

```
@article{zhang2010interest,
title={Interest-oriented versus relationship-oriented social network sites      in China},
author={Zhang, Weiyu and Wang, Rong},
journal={First Monday},
volume={15},
number={8},
year={2010}
 }
```

But what it gets printed is this:

(4)  Zhang, W.; Wang, R.First Monday2010,15.

Im using achemso package:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}

\newcommand*{\mycommand}[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\setcitestyle{numbers,square}
```

Answer (score 1):

To benefit from the features offered by achemso, loading it in the preamble is only one thing.  If you want to apply this as a style of your bibliography, the body of your *.tex has to include the lines

```
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{myreferences}
```

Your example however calls one the built-in standard styles, hence the output misses items and does not follow the style, either.  (If you change from an earlier citation style to a new one, it is better to remove the old intermediate files [like *.bbl] generated during the compilation first.)

If preparing a publication (prior to submission), especially while sharing drafts with contributors, I find it helpful to have at least the first of the two following extras enabled, hence suggest to use a preamble stating

```
\usepackage[articletitle=true, doi=true]{achemso}
```

Depending on the journal's policy, these are adapted / removed prior to submission.

As a final hint, for a submission to ACS, stay with BibTeX; their system is not yet able to handle e-TeX, hence BibLaTeX is not understood.  (Not a problem with [Zotero's](http://www.zotero.org) extensions like [BetterBibTeX](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) as one example of literature management software, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{achemso}

\setkeys{acs}{articletitle=true}

\begin{document}

...


\bibliographystyle{achemso}

\bibliography{JPC-bib}

\end{document}
```